# Aplicar una operacion compleja a una columna para obtener un nuevo data frame en R

Tags: r, dataframe, r-dplyr

Tengo un dataframe que es similar al siguiente, llamemoslo DF.

```
|Symbol |   Date    | volume |price |
|------------------------------------
|A      |2014-01-01 | 1      |   5  |
|A      |2014-01-02 | 3      |   8  |
|A      |2014-01-03 | 7      |   4  |
|A      |2014-01-07 |3       |   6  |
|A      |2014-01-08 |34      |   7  |
|A      |2014-01-09 |45      |  34  |
|A      |2014-01-10 |4       |   5  | 
|A      |2014-01-11 |9       |   7  |
|A      |2014-01-14 |8       |   6  |
|A      |2014-01-15 |4       |   4  |
|A      |2014-01-16 |0       |   7  |
|A      |2014-01-17 |4       |   7  |
```

Quiero aplicar la siguiente operación a la columna de precio:

```
diff(log(DF$price))
```

Y generar el siguiente dataframe:

```
|   Date    | returns|
|--------------------
|2014-01-01 | 4      | 
|2014-01-02 | 6      |  
|2014-01-03 | 8      |  
|2014-01-07 | 2      |  
|2014-01-08 | 14     |   
|2014-01-09 | 5      |  
|2014-01-10 | 1      |    
|2014-01-11 | 2      |   
|2014-01-14 |8       |  
|2014-01-15 |4       |  
|2014-01-16 |0       |   
|2014-01-17 |4       |
```

(Los números en la columna returns son solo  ejemplos, no son los buscados, en realidad, necesito en cada fila de la columna el resultado de `diff(log(DF$price))`)

Trate de usar las siguientes líneas de código, pero no resultó:

```
Ret <- DF %>% group_by(date) %>%
  mutate(Ret_i = diff(log(DF$price)))%>%
  summarise(Ret_i)
```

Gracias por leer, cualquier ayuda será muy apreciada

Comment: A no ser que este entendiendo mal tu pregunta, el calculo debiera estar en el summarize, algo así: `df %>% group_by(Date) %>% summarise(Ret_i = diff(log(df$price)))`

Comment: Sí, muchas gracias, es lo que necesitaba!

Answer (score 0):

La función Diff devuelve las diferencias, por tanto el número de datos resultante de la operación es nrow(DF) - 1. Por eso el mensaje de error hace referencia a un error en el primer registro.

Yo lo haría en dos líneas:

```
Ret <- DF %>% group_by(Date) %>% summarise(precio = sum(price))
Ret$Ret_i <- c(0,diff(log(Ret$precio)))
```